# How to pretty-print arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

So I have this question where I shall print arrays.
The output should be like this:

> {element0, element1, element2}

so I have written this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

main() {
    int a[10] = {1, 0, 3, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8, 15, 14};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("{%d, }", a[10]);
    }
}
```

Ok, so well how in the world can I write out all the numbers in one line, where they are supposed to be inbetween curly brackets and spaced by commas. I assume you are supposed to use some kindof pointer that points to all the numbers. But I am new to this and have never learnt this and its quite tricky..

Yes but i think i am supposed to use **pointers** if I am not mistaken.

Comment: First thing I noticed: as a general rule of thumb, you'll want to use the variable you're incrementing as your array index, e.g. something like `a[i]`. You need to do some more research on arrays as this is a very basic and Googleable question.

Comment: Change `printf("{%d, }", a[10]);` to `printf("{%d, }", a[i]);`

Comment: You know, not using proper prototypes is a bad idea, even if when it works.

Answer (score 5):

#### Analysis

Dissecting the code in the question more or less line by line.

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

The standard uses `#include <stdio.h>`; you had better know enough about C not to need to ask this question before you use anything else.

```
main()
```

This has not been legitimate standard C since 1999 (for all that some C compilers still accept it without whingeing).  You should always declare the return type.  I'd use `int main(void)` because that way I don't get errors from my default compiler options, but you could use `int main()`.

```
{
    int a[10]= {1, 0, 3, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8, 15, 14};
    int i;
```

Although the code above is OK, a C99 compiler would allow you to write `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` and omit the definition of `i` before the loop.

```
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("{%d, }", a[10]);
    }
```

As pointed out by others, the `a[10]` is wrong.  It is wrong because it should be `a[i]`, and because `a[10]` is beyond the end of the array, so you invoke undefined behaviour.

```
}
```

You don't ensure that a newline appears, and you don't return a status to the environment.  If you write C89 code, you should have `return 0;` at the end (but you can get away with the original declaration of `main()`).  If you don't have `return 0;` at the end to use the grace given by the C99 standard, you must have `int main(void)` or similar at the top.  You can't have it both ways at once.

#### Synthesis

The question was updated to indicate that pointers are to be used and that `if (i != 0)` probably isn't allowed inside the body of the loop.  In that case, I'd probably write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[10] = { 1, 0, 3, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8, 15, 14 };
    int *p = &a[0];
    int *end = &a[10];
    char *pad = "{ ";

    while (p < end)
    {
        printf("%s%d", pad, *p++);
        pad = ", ";
    }
    printf(" }\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It is legitimate to form the address of `a[10]` and to compare pointers with it, but it is not legitimate to dereference it (to use `a[10]`).  The code places a space after the `{` and before the `}` because that's how I like the data to appear.  If you want no space there, omit the space.  If you want no space after the commas, omit that too.  I find the 'pad' technique quite useful and use it quite often in these scenarios.  You can beef up the printing code to handle bigger arrays that have to be split over multiple lines (though that is easier using array indexes than using pointers), and other similar variants.

Sample output:

```
{ 1, 0, 3, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8, 15, 14 }
```

If you have multi-line output, you might want to have the numbers nicely aligned.  In that case, you have to use a conversion specification such as `%2d` to get all numbers right aligned in columns that are 2 digits wide.

#### Generalization

A more general solution would use a function to do the printing, more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_array(int *array, int size)
{
    int *p = array;
    int *end = array + size;
    char *pad = "{ ";

    while (p < end)
    {
        printf("%s%d", pad, *p++);
        pad = ", ";
    }
    printf(" }\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[10] = { 1, 0, 3, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8, 15, 14 };
    print_array(a, 10);
    print_array(a, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you could do it like this

```
printf("{");
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (i != 0) printf(", ");
    printf("%d", a[i]);
}
printf("}\n");
```

Output is (the expected)

```
{1, 0, 3, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8, 15, 14}
```

Comment: I dont think i am supposed to use i !=0

Comment: @user3808326: waddya mean?  If there are ridiculous pedagogic constraints on your solution imposed by tutors, outline them because the chances of real solutions not running foul of them are usually minimal.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include "stdio.h"

main()
{

    int[10] a= {1, 0, 3, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8, 15, 14};
    printf("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
        if(i < 9)
            printf(",");
    }
    printf("}");
}
```

Comment: Sorry was just fixing his syntax didn't look at the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[10]= {1, 0, 3, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8, 15, 14};
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%.*s%d%.*s%.*s", (!i), "{", a[i], 2*(i<9), ", ", (i==9)*2, "}\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider altering the `format` in the loop.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(void) {
  int a[10]= {1, 0, 3, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8, 15, 14};
  size_t i;

  const char *format = "%d";
  fputs("{", stdout);
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    printf(format, a[i]);
    format = ", %d";
  }
  fputs("}\n", stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

The above approach also works well if the array count was 1 or even 0.